# How many distinguishable ways can the letters of the word MATHEMATICS be arranged in order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I understand permutations and combinations, but I'm a little confused on what "in order" means in this case.

Wouldn't this just be 1?  Since MATHEMATICS can only be written "in order" as MATHEMATICS?

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Most likely, the "in order" part refers to the common notion of two words $W_1,\ W_2$ being the same if and only if the first letter on the left of $W_1$ is the same as the first letter to the left of $W_2$, the second ones to the left as well and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is $11$ letter and $2$ M, $2$ T and $2$ A, you get $$\frac{11!}{2!2!2!}=\binom{11}{2,2,2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just don't think about it being the word Mathematics. It simply means, if you have given:
- Two M's
- Two A's
- Two T's
- One H, E, I, C, S

How many different words can you make? For example, if you have a given word and you swap two A's, you get the same word. But if you swap a T and a M, you get a different word.